# What is the meaning of adding ondragstart="return false;" to an <img> tag?

Tags: html, image

I found some web pages have added

`ondragstart="return false;"` to an `<img>` tag like this:

```
<img ondragstart="return false;" src="...." .....
```

May I know what's the benefit from it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It just makes the image undraggable, preventing this:
[image]

Which could also be achieved using a `background-image` with css instead `<img>` tag.

Comment: May I know what benefit would that get? Or what's the problem/rish if I allow a user to drag?

Comment: @AGamePlayer It could be purely aesthetics. UX wise, it could be because the app has a lot of draggable components, and the user might think they can drag the image (as an app functionality) too, so preventing it could improve the UX.

Answer (score 1):

[`ondragstart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/ondragstart) is used in conjunction with `draggable="true"` to trigger a function on a draggable element:

```
 <div draggable="true" ondragstart="function()">
```

This can be seen here:

```js
var dragged;

/* events fired on the draggable target */
document.addEventListener("drag", function(event) {
}, false);

document.addEventListener("dragstart", function(event) {
  // store a ref. on the dragged elem
  dragged = event.target;
  // make it half transparent
  event.target.style.opacity = .5;
}, false);

document.addEventListener("dragend", function(event) {
  // reset the transparency
  event.target.style.opacity = "";
}, false);

/* events fired on the drop targets */
document.addEventListener("dragover", function(event) {
  // prevent default to allow drop
  event.preventDefault();
}, false);

document.addEventListener("dragenter", function(event) {
  // highlight potential drop target when the draggable element enters it
  if (event.target.className == "dropzone") {
    event.target.style.background = "purple";
  }
}, false);

document.addEventListener("dragleave", function(event) {
  // reset background of potential drop target when the draggable element leaves it
  if (event.target.className == "dropzone") {
    event.target.style.background = "";
  }
}, false);

document.addEventListener("drop", function(event) {
  // prevent default action (open as link for some elements)
  event.preventDefault();
  // move dragged elem to the selected drop target
  if (event.target.className == "dropzone") {
    event.target.style.background = "";
    dragged.parentNode.removeChild(dragged);
    event.target.appendChild(dragged);
  }
}, false);
```

```css
#draggable {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
}

.dropzone {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  background: blueviolet;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropzone">
  <div id="draggable" draggable="true" ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain',null)">
    This div is draggable
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropzone"></div>
<div class="dropzone"></div>
<div class="dropzone"></div>
```

The `return false` in the example is shorthand for stating that the function does nothing, and is essentially completely extraneous.

Also note that while `ondragstart` can be processed by mobile devices, [the dragstart event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/dragstart_event) is **not** compatible with mobile, so to ensure dragging for mobile devices you will want to use [`touchstart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/touchstart_event) instead.